# How to implement a full adder using only AND, XOR gates

Tags: logic-gates

The question is that I have 3 inputs (X,Y,Z) and two outputs (S,C). I have to implement a full adder circuit **using only AND-XOR** gates. I did a little bit of research but I couldn't figure out a way to implement it using only the given gates. Here is an screenshot of a full adder circuit. The only problem with this implementation is the OR gate.
[image]

Is it possible to implement a **full adder using only AND-XOR gates**? If possible any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you add a link to your logic simulation - it looks like one of the many online simulators - then others can play around with it and maybe offer you some help. [Edit] the link into your question. Don't hide it down here in the comments.

Comment: No i didn't use any online websites. I designed this in Logicly and just took an screenshot.

Comment: https://logic.ly/demo/ ***is*** an online simulator. If you use that and provide a link then we can all play with it.

Comment: Well, you could research ways to make an OR gate out of what you have. (NB : it doesn't have to be elegant!)

Comment: Here is the link https://ufile.io/khlrxo7s

Comment: i did search about implementing or gates with and but nothing useful as usual

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house or homework-answering service. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question to show your own work, own conclusions and own findings in considerable detail. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: @Sahar I'm sure you must have found a "half adder" made from an AND and XOR. (You can't avoid seeing one like that.) And everywhere you can find the case where two half-adders (obviously made from AND and XOR) are used in a full adder. Is it your *only* problem that you cannot find on the web (so you may need to think for yourself) that all the full adders appear to be using an extra OR gate, as well? Is it that you cannot imagine a new way of combining things so as to replace the OR? Are you permitted to supply a 1 input? Or is that banned?

Comment: The only problem i have with my implementation is the OR gate which is odd. Since it is not possible to implement OR gate using XOR i think i have to change my question. I juat need help implementing a 2 input OR gate using and gates only.

Comment: Look up "DeMorgan's theorum" - how to create any gate from (almost) any other. You need something with an invert function in the mix. Which you have got.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/de-morgans-theorem#:~:text=De%20Morgan's%20Theorem%2C%20T12%2C%20is,the%20complement%20of%20each%20term.&text=According%20to%20De%20Morgan's%20theorem,OR%20gate%20with%20inverted%20inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an OR gate if you invert the inputs and outputs of the AND using XOR gates wired as inverters. That's inelegant but it works.

That’s just one way, there are others. A hint: a full-adder is realizable as a pair of cascaded half-adders.

Another hint: [Why is the last carry block's gate in a full adder an OR gate (and not a XOR)?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/492236/why-is-the-last-carry-blocks-gate-in-a-full-adder-an-or-gate-and-not-a-xor?rq=1)

Comment: Can you please provide an screenshot of your implementation?

Comment: @Sahar Welcome to EE.SE. As you will probably note from now on, we use the Socratic Method for this type of question. You may update your question to show your progress or how you are stuck after trying to apply the tip given here.

Comment: I guess i have to study more about this method before solving this question.

Comment: @Sahar. It just means we won't provide the final answer but will be glad to help you find it.

Answer (score 1):

You already got the S output.

Tips:

1. Can you make an inverter (one input and one output) using a XOR and connecting one of the inputs to a fixed level?
2. You can make any circuit using NANDs, right?

As @user_1818839 said, it doesn't have to be elegant!

Comment: No thats the problem. The only gates i have to use are XOR-AND gates.

Comment: Well, figure out if either of those can be used as an inverter!